# MySQL: call procedure from function

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to call a procedure from a function in MySQL? I get the error "not allowed to return a result set from a function." I want the results of the procedure call to be inserted into the function variables the same as if I had done a SELECT INTO directly in the function.

The function is (simplified) defined as

```
create function my_function()
   returns int deterministic
   begin
     declare some_parameter int;
     declare the_result int;

     call my_procedure(some_parameter, the_result)

     return the_result;

   end;
```

The procedure is (simplified) defined as:

```
create procedure my_procedure(in my_parameter int, out my_result int)
    begin
        select 1 
        from dual;
   end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, no. Functions are looking for a datatype, not a record (which is what is returned from the procedure).